# How to remove items from a list (Dart) | Firebase rtdb

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-streambuilder

I have a list that stores items that I don't want to display as part of my `StreamBuilder`, `ListView`. This list retrieves its information from a `firebase rtdb`.

I use a `StreamBuilder` to populate the `ListView`, and then I use a `for-loop` to try and iterate through the list that contains items I don't want to display. So far I can get the `ListView` populated, but the items removed from the StreamBuilder aren't accurate.

Below is how I have approached it (Any help is much appreciated):

**I can confirm that the list definitely contains the info I don't want displayed**

```
ListView.builder(
    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: friends.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final friend = friends[index];

      if (friend.userID == uid){
        return null;
      } else {

        for (FriendSuggestionModel hidden in hiddenSuggestions){
          if (hidden.userID == friend.userID){
            return null;
          } else {
            return friendThumbnail(index, friend);
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I believe you need to return a Widget in itemBuilder, so don't use **return null** instead you can return an empty container with **return Container()**.

You also could use **list.contains(x)** method to verify if this id should be hide (as I imagine , as follows:

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final friend = friends[index];

      if (friend.userID == uid){
        return const Container();
      } else {
        return hiddenSuggestions.map((hidden) => hidden.userID).toList().contains(friend.userID)
          ? const Container()
          : friendThumbnail(index, friend);
      }
    }
```

Check that method docs here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html

Comment: Thank you for the response @Leonardo! There were minor issues with syntax, but I have fixed them and it's working as expected - shall I edit your response and mark it as accepted?

Comment: I couldn't edit the above comment, but it is correct! I just removed the return statements after the "?" and "!". Also, the line with the mapping should be: `return hiddenSuggestions.map((hidden) => hidden.userID).toList().contains(friend.userID)`

Comment: I edited to help anyone with the same doubt, thanks. I think this should be the accepted response